# How to click on activation link in the mail in cucumber feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I have as usual common functionality as after sign up user receives confirmation mail which contains activation link.
After clicking on that link user is confirmed and then only he can sign in to the respective system.
So, how to get mail and how to click on that activation link using cucumber features?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this
[email-spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec)

You can use defined step

```
When I follow "activate" in the email
```

And [here](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec/blob/master/lib/generators/email_spec/steps/templates/email_steps.rb) is list of defined steps.

Comment: Thanks for this, this will actually help me a lot, I'm surprised I hadn't seen it yet. @trupti this will likely be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just testing the code that generates the link. So in your step definition just goto the `activation_url(@user)` or whatever you use to generate the link. Interacting with mail is a bit of a pain, your tests will be cleaner if you just test the mail sent, and then separately test the code that generates the url.

**EDIT for example**

```
Given /^I have been sent an activation email$/ do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:unactived_user)
end

When /^I click on the activation link$/ do
  visit(activation_url(@user)
end

Then /^I should see a success message$/ do
  page.has_content('Success!')
end
```

This is assuming you're using FactoryGirl and Capybara, and already have an 'unactived_user' setup in your Factory.rb file.

Comment: Thanks FluffyJack...But can i get exact steps for checking the activation functionality?

Comment: I can't really know exactly what your setup is, but I'll edit my answer with an example.